# Add a list inside another and serialize with JSON.net

Tags: c#, .net, json, winforms

I'll try to be as specific as possible.
I have a system for registering customers. By registering a customer, it is added to my List and to my customers listbox with the following code:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public static List<Customer> Customers = new List<Customer>();

private void btnRegisterCustomer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Customer customer = new Customer();
    customer.CustomerNumber = textboxNumber.Text;
    customer.Name = textboxName.Text;
    customersList.Items.Add(customer.Name);
    Customers.Add(customer);
}
```

To save to file the customer data I use:

```
File.WriteAllText(customersFILE, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Customers, Formatting.Indented));
```

This works great. Now I will explain my issue.
I'm trying to register a product to the selected customer in the listbox. My system of product registration is the same as the customer. I need to add the selected product in the products listbox to the selected customer. I need something like this in my JSON output:

```
[
    {
      "CustomerNumber": "001",
      "Name": "Jack",
      "Bought": [
                    {
                         "ProductName": "Boat", "ProductPrice": "20000", //I don't know if sintax is correct
                         "ProductName": "Car", "ProductPrice": "23000"
                    }
                ]
    }
]
```

What I want is basically add the selected product in the listbox to the selected customer selected in another listbox. I've tried something by this way:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<PurchasedProduct> Bought { get; set; }
}

public class PurchasedProduct
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductPrice { get; set; }
}

public static List<PurchasedProduct> PurchasedProducts = new List<PurchasedProduct>();

private void btnRegisterProductToCustomer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PurchasedProduct purchased = PurchasedProducts[customersListBox.SelectedIndex];
    purchased.ProductName = productNameTextBox.Text;
    purchased.ProductPrice = productPriceTextBox.Text;
    PurchasedProducts.Add(purchased);
    foreach (var product in purchased.ProductName)
        {
            purchasedProductsListBox.Items.Add(purchased);
        }
}
```

This don't work.
I have this to show the selected customer info:

```
private void customersListBoxSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Customer customer = Customers[customersListBox.SelectedIndex];
    labelCustomerNumber.Text = customer.CustomerNumber;
    labelCustomerName.Text = customer.Name;
    //I need now to display the info about the selected purchased product
    purchasedProductsListBox.Items.Clear();
    if (customer.Bought != null)
    {
        foreach (var productB in customer.Bought[customersListBox.SelectedIndex].Name)
        {
            purchasedProductsListBox.Items.Add(productB);
        }
    }
}
```

I need to get the customer selected purchased product values ​​and then display them in labels like the customer values, but first I have to figure out how to store the product data in the List and serialize with JSON.

Comment: The logic in your "btnRegisterProductToCustomer_Click" method is not totally clear to me: You first retrieve a product from your PurchasedProducts via an index and after that you add the same product again to the list, why is that?

Comment: `PurchasedProducts[customersListBox.SelectedIndex]` looks fishy.  Just from the name, wouldn't `customersListBox.SelectedIndex` be an index in a list of customers?  Also, `foreach (var product in purchased.ProductName)` - `ProductName` is a string, so you are looping through characters?

Comment: @dbc That's the point. I do not know how to do this so I was trying in my way. I would like your help to develop a code that works correctly. 
When I select a customer in the listbox, there is another listbox to show the products he bought. So when I change the selected customer in the listbox I use Items.Clear and then try to add the currently selected customer products to the list.

Comment: @hatdev01 I try to add the products he bought to be shown in another listbox. The purchasedProductsListBox.

Comment: I suggest looking at the MVC controller method that accommodates IEnumerable<ofType> as an example.  I cannot recall if it handles fileds within <ofType> that are "Complex"... such as "Customer" above.  However, where there's a will there's a way. https://www.google.com/search?q=mvc+json&oq=mvc+json&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1694j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8